# Parsing speech out of text

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, parsing, role-playing-game

I'm working on an experiment to parse speech out of an emote in a text roleplaying game (MUD) so that if you can't hear it correctly, or if it's in a different language, you won't understand it. This works correctly, but I was just wanting to make sure it was as clear and efficient as possible.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class EmoteParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an emote: ");
        String emote = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Original emote:\n" + emote);
        System.out.println("\nParsed emote:\n" + jumbleEmoteSpeech(emote));
    }

    public static String jumbleEmoteSpeech(String emote) {
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        int quote1Location = emote.indexOf('"');

        if (quote1Location == -1) {
            out.append(emote);
        }
        else {
            int quote2Location;
            int currentIndex = 0;
            boolean found = true;
            do {
                quote2Location = emote.indexOf('"', quote1Location + 1);
                if (quote2Location == -1 || quote2Location < currentIndex) {
                    out.append(emote.substring(currentIndex));
                    found = false;
                }
                else {
                    out.append(emote.substring(currentIndex, quote1Location + 1));
                    out.append(jumble(emote.substring(quote1Location + 1, quote2Location)));
                    currentIndex = quote2Location;

                    quote1Location = emote.indexOf('"', currentIndex + 1);
                }
            } while (found);
        }

        return out.toString();
    }

    public static String jumble(String text) {
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        Random generator = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char ch = text.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                    out.append((char)('A' + generator.nextInt(26)));
                }
                else {
                    out.append((char)('a' + generator.nextInt(26)));
                }
            }
            else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                out.append((char)('0' + generator.nextInt(10)));
            }
            else {
                out.append(text.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        return out.toString();
    }
}
```

Also, is there any real benefit to using `'"'` vs `"\""`? I think `'"'` is more readable, and any performance difference is probably optimized out anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The `jumble` method

In the `jumble` method, you are looping over the character by having an index going from 0 to the length of the input array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char ch = text.charAt(i);
    // ...
}
```

Since you don't use the index apart from retrieve the character, you couls just use `toCharArray()` and loop directly over the characters:

```
for (char ch : text.toCharArray()) {
    // ...
}
```

Then, you are appending characters based on their codepoint. For this, you are doing

```
out.append((char) ('A' + generator.nextInt(26))); // same for 'a' and '0'
```

Instead of having this (ugly) cast, you could directly use [`appendCodePoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#appendCodePoint-int-) with

```
out.appendCodePoint('A' + generator.nextInt(26));
```

Additionally, the code path to jumble a character can lead to potential bugs:

```
if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
} else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that `isLetter` returns `true` for characters that are not only uppercase or lowercase characters. For example, it would return true for [all those weird characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lo/list.htm) classified as "Lo" as per Unicode (and `OTHER_LETTER` in Java). It would also return `true` for [those classified "Lm"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lm/list.htm) (`MODIFIER_LETTER` in Java), like "OL CHIKI AHAD" ᱽ. Since I think that, for example, in the case of the Hebrew letter "BET", ב, you don't want to consider it lowercase (which your code would, since it is a letter not uppercase), you can remove that check completely and have:

```
if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
    sb.appendCodePoint('A' + generator.nextInt(26));
} else if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
    sb.appendCodePoint('a' + generator.nextInt(26));
} else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
    sb.appendCodePoint('0' + generator.nextInt(10));
} else {
    sb.append(ch);
}
```

This way, only character that have case (upper or lower) will be taken into account in those branches. But still, [there are a lot of lowercase letters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm) (and [uppercase letters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm)) different than `a-z`, like ῲ or ⅎ or even ⱙ (which is apparently "GLAGOLITIC SMALL LETTER IOTATED BIG YUS"). In those case, they will be replaced by a Latin small character, which may or may not be what you want. If you truly want to jumble only Latin letters, it would be best to test the character against `'a'` and `'z'` (conversely for uppercase). And you know what? This is not just letters. [There are a lot of digits](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) that aren't `0-9`, like ٨ (Arabic 8) or ᧗ (New Tai Lue 7) or even ꧓ (which is apparently Javanese 3). Therefore, if you just want to concentrate on Latin letters and Roman digits, you can just use

```
if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
    sb.appendCodePoint('A' + generator.nextInt(26));
} else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
    sb.appendCodePoint('a' + generator.nextInt(26));
} else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
    sb.appendCodePoint('0' + generator.nextInt(10));
} else {
    sb.append(ch);
}
```

The last concern is about the `Random` object. You are creating one each time this method is executed. It would be preferable to create only one [and reuse the same everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11323245/1743880). For example, you can have a constant

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
```

#### The `jumbleEmoteSpeech` method

You should always prefer to return early from methods when it is possible. In this case, if there are no quotes in the String, you return it unchanged.

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
int quote1Location = emote.indexOf('"');
if (quote1Location == -1) {
    out.append(emote);
} else {
    // ...
}
return out.toString();
```

You could write this more concisely with

```
int quote1Location = emote.indexOf('"');
if (quote1Location == -1) {
    return emote;
}
// ...
```

This accomplishes two things:

- There is no `StringBuilder` created: we don't need one
- The code is more readable because the `else` part isn't needed anymore: it shifts the rest with one indentation less.

Also, prefer to declare variables at the moment of use. In this case, you are declaring `int quote2Location;` before the `while` loop:

```
int quote2Location;
do {
    quote2Location = emote.indexOf('"', quote1Location + 1);
    // ...
} while (...);
```

Instead, you can just have:

```
do {
    int quote2Location = emote.indexOf('"', quote1Location + 1);
    // ...
} while (...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer!! Regarding the `Random` object, would it be a good idea to just have a global generator, and use that generator for everything for the duration of the game, or keep it static to this class? With the creation of the `int`s at the moment of use, do they not need to be created each iteration of the loop? (That was why it did it right before, but if the compiler knows better, that's awesome to know!)

Comment: @BrainFRZ Yes, the `Random` object should be reused through-out the whole game. If its only used in one class, you can make `static final` in this class.  Note that if you intent to generate random numbers in multiple classes, you should use instead `ThreadLocalRandom` and acquire one with `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` at the moment of generation (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23396033/1743880) for the difference). In this case, no need for a constant `static final`.